# ArcGIS 10 attribute table sort issue

Tags: attribute-table

what is the solution for this funky sorting Esri does in attribute tables with decimal places values... screen shot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q95Zg.png [attribute table funky sort](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q95Zg.png)

Comment: Based on character positioning and sort results, I'd say MP is a text-type field. See answers re:character/text fields; Emily and I posted similar answers at the same time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like **MP** is a character field, thus the *weird* sort. That sort looks normal for a character field. Try creating a new field, e.g. "**MP_Num**", as a numeric field, then calculate the values of **MP_Num** based on String-to-Number conversion of **MP**.

edit: I just noticed the ET_STATION field looks to be the numeric equivalent of MP, so you may not need to make a new field. Try sorting on ET_STATION.

Answer (score 5):

What type is your field? If it's a text type, it will alphabetise it and therefore put everything starting with 1 first. Make a new field of a numerical type and it will sort properly.

edit: Also I just tested this on a table of my own with decimal places of type DOUBLE and it does not sort like this. But it does do it for the text label field I have.

Comment: Thanks Kevin and Emily, i knew it was something simple like that... screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/E5IFv.png

Answer (score 3):

Your field is a text field and if you want to sort it properly, then it needs to be padded with zeros.  There are various ways of doing this, an example is 
[shown here](http://forums.arcgis.com/threads/35137-Populate-a-field-with-consecutive-numbers-by-a-constant-length-string.?p=119553#post119553)
which can be implemented within the field calculator if using ArcMap and I am sure other programs that support Python or Python-like syntax

EDIT

Then you can always use zfill to pad your rows if you are using the field calculator and the Python parser, you just .

```
>>> "17.98".zfill(8)
'00017.98'
```

eg, convert to a string then pad

```
>>> a = 17.98
>>> b = str(a).zfill(8)
>>> b
'00017.98'
>>>
```